# Create package that references another package in solution

Tags: nuget-package, paket

I often have this situation:

```
Foo.sln
    Foo.csproj
    Foo.Wpf.csproj
```

Then I create:

- A nuget package `Foo.nupkg`
- A package for `Foo.Wpf.nupkg` referencing `Foo.nupkg`.

I could not find out how to specify that dependency in [the docs](http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/template-files.html#Dependencies).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a paket.template for each project and make sure you set the "type" property to "project". Paket will figure things out automatically for you

**Edit:**

Sample:

```
Foo.sln
    Foo.csproj
        paket.template
    Foo.Wpf.csproj
        paket.template
```

Where the `paket.template` files looks like this:

```
type project
// This assumes that Author and Version are specified in the project.
```

If you want to override the defaults check out [the docs](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/template-files.html)